# flow_from_data_frame gives wrong label shape in multioutput classification in keras

Tags: python, pandas, keras, preprocessor

I am currently trying to train a multi-output-classification network in keras. The .csv has 4 categories, which are all classes from {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}. My network has a softmax dense layer as its output layer, but trying to train gives me the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,4] and labels shape [128]
     [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at /engagement_detector/cnn/train.py:58) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1752]
```

Since my batch size is 32 in both training as well as the generator, I would have thought both would be of shape [32, 4].
Here is the code I used for the generator:

```
    datagen = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df,
    directory=subdir,
    x_col="ClipID",
    y_col=list(df.columns.drop("ClipID")),
    subset=subset.lower(),
    batch_size=32,
    seed=42,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode="raw",
    target_size=(32, 32))
```

Did I do something wrong or could someone help me with resizing the generator output? I tried adding a reshape layer, but could not get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried reshaping your label? It's the same linear dimension as the input batches.

Comment: I actually don't know how or where. I am just passing the whole generator into model.fit as x. Datagen._targets.shape ist already (17571, 4), 17571 being the number of samples.

Comment: can you upload your .csv file somehow, an screenshot should suffice?

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://imgur.com/013gzVP

Comment: try using `multi_output` instead of `raw` and see what happens.

Comment: Doing that makes the generator output lists of 4 arrays as labels in `for data, label in generator`. The arrays all contain 32 ints, so the axis seems off?
When trying to call fit, it eventually throws `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'`